# @hourly vs 0 * * * * - Cron - How to run jobs hourly, but at different times

Tags: cron, scheduling

I have jobs that I want to run hourly, but not necessarily at the same time, which I think

```
0 * * * * job
```

Means run at the 0 minute of every hour on the dot.

I know I can also use

```
@hourly job
```

**What is the difference if any?
How can I schedule Jobs to run Hourly, but not all at the same time?**

Comment: Does cron do this automatically?

Comment: *"I know I can also use `@hourly * * * * job`"* No you cannot; that would be `@hourly job`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [`crontab(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html#EXTENSIONS):

> `@hourly`:    Run once an hour, ie. `"0 * * * *"`.

So it's strictly the same.

To run a job at a varying point in the hour (or multiple jobs, to spread the load) you can sleep for a random amount of time before starting the job:

```
@hourly sleep $((RANDOM / 10)); dowhatever
```

This sleeps for up to 3276 seconds (nearly an hour), then runs the job. So every time `cron` starts the job, it waits a different amount of time before actually starting.

Comment: Well I might just use Jenkins then, it seems to automatically pick a random time close to what I put in "build Periodically". I can see that being a blessing and a curse, I understand why Cron doesn't do it, sometimes things need to be exact, but in this case your assumption is correct, I want to balance load. I'm choosing this as an answer because it offered a solution. Thankz

Comment: I suppose I could put all the jobs in a single script and at least then they would be executed one at a time vs simultaneously.

Comment: If you're running build jobs then a tool like Jenkins is probably better suited. Having everything run sequentially in a script will avoid overloading the system, but it might underuse the system too.

Comment: @StephenKitt Wonderful answer, but I'd specify the value, like @Igniter suggests, using `$(( RANDOM % 3600))`
The implicit value, which I guess is "up to 32767", isn't obvious

Comment: @Balmipour I tend to avoid modulus on random values because of the resulting bias (not that that would matter much here...).

Comment: There would be a little bias with modulo, but not too much, maybe around 10% tops.  A bigger concern is using `%` in a crontab because it needs backslash-escaping.

Answer (score 8):

`@hourly` is an exact synonym of `0 * * * *` in `crontab`, there is no difference. `@hourly` is a special string representation for `0 * * * *`.

From `man 5 crontab`:

```
string         meaning
------         -------
@hourly        Run once an hour, "0 * * * *".
```

Just to note, there are 8 special strings in total supported by the `cron` i have, Vixie Cron.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to share Jenkins Cron/Build Periodically Methodology. Would be nice to see something like this in regular Cron where H(hash) was an option

```
Examples:

# every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
H/15 * * * *
# every ten minutes in the first half of every hour (three times, perhaps at :04, :14, :24)
H(0-29)/10 * * * *
# once every two hours at 45 minutes past the hour starting at 9:45 AM and finishing at 3:45 PM every weekday.
45 9-16/2 * * 1-5
# once in every two hours slot between 9 AM and 5 PM every weekday (perhaps at 10:38 AM, 12:38 PM, 2:38 PM, 4:38 PM)
H H(9-16)/2 * * 1-5
# once a day on the 1st and 15th of every month except December
H H 1,15 1-11 *
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also explicitly limit your time boundaries using the **modulus operator**.
This is how to do it if you want to limit the launch to max 10 minutes (600 sec):

> `$RANDOM % 600` will yield results between 0 and 600:
>
> ```
> @hourly sleep $(( $RANDOM % 600 )) && /path/to/your/script
> ```
>
> Using `&&` here, since `sleep` will be executed anyway.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers notice the difference between `/` and `%`, sometimes it's much more easier to explicitly limit sleep to X minutes, than trying to calculate how to obtain X minutes by division and how many seconds are there in an hour